# Cannot save and access images (Laravel)

Tags: laravel-5

I am having a problem with accessing images.

I can upload and receive an image to the database no problem; however, I have my images manually saved under the **`public/avatar`** folder and I can retrieve the images from that location by using:

**`{{ asset('/uploads/avatars/image.jpg }}`**

I cannot figure out how to save to that location; I've tried the following to no avail:

**`Storage::disk('local')->put('/uploads/avatars/', $image);`**

Also, when I try to save from the controller it saves everything in **`storage/app/public`**, but I don't know how to access the image files from the model nor how to save them somewhere else.

Comment: What package are you using to manage images?

Answer (score 0):

When you use this

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('/uploads/avatars/', $image);
```

then all of your images are store in `storage/app/uploads/avatars` directory. so you can not access it from public directory. If you want to access it from public directory, you have to make a symbolic link of `storage/app/uploads/avatars` in public directory. I think it work fine :)